# Filter value with conditional logic with SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table as below:

```
store       city         status
  a        new york        t
  b        paris           f
  b        london          t 
  c        lisbon          f
```

I would like to select the store when it ONLY has 'f' value. If the store has both 'f' and 't' then it does not count. Desired Output:

```
store            status
  c                f
```

This is what I have tried but I still did not get the desired output:

```
SELECT store
FROM (
      SELECT store, city,
             CASE 
                 WHEN status = 'f' THEN 1
                 WHEN status = 't' THEN -1 
             END AS status
      FROM table) AS t
GROUP BY store 
HAVING SUM(status) > 1
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aggregation and `having`:

```
select store
from t
group by store
having min(status) = 'f' and max(status) = 'f';
```